# How does meteorology resist Popperian analysis?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, popper, francis-bacon

Graham Rees (who takes what one could say is a "middle of the road" approach to appraising Bacon's relevance to the practice of science in our times) writes in [a 2002 article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3817980) that (as a saving grace for the Baconian conception of the scientific method):

> meteorology and demographic studies (areas to which Bacon himself devoted seminal natural-historical
> works) resist Popperian analysis. Or again, look at the sciences that study systems so complex that predictive
> theories cannot deliver satisfactory explanations of the phenomena.
> Look in particular at vital fields within artificial intelligence, or in materials
> science and pharmaceuticals research, where hypothetico-deductive methods barely exist
> and inductive combinatorial models to search vast databases take over.
> [...] Where there are no conjectures, refutations will be scarce. Perhaps it is time to reinstate Bacon in philosophy of science curricula after all.

I should add here for more context that Rees doesn't dig the Urbach view that sees Popper prefigurated all over Bacon's works; Rees gave a rather scathing [review](https://www.jstor.org/stable/234732) to Urbach's works, accusing them of historical & textual inaccuracies among other things.

But to get to my question, leaving aside "demographic studies", which perhaps indeed are more descriptive if one considers them in the sense of census data rather than sociological models, can one really claim that meteorology isn't full of predictive models that are used every day? In that sense Rees' claim seems obviously false to me, as some models are better at weather predictions that others, so meteorology is substantially affected by a core "Popperian" issue. Can Rees mean something else by that claim that "meteorology resist[s] Popperian analysis?"

Comment: I've only read The Logic of Scientific Discovery so my understanding may be wrong/incomplete, but at least there he seems to say that a falsifier of a theory must be a proposition such that *if* we accept it as true, the theory must be absolutely impossible to reconcile with it, not just that the theory becomes less probable or any such "graded" notion. He does allow that the truth of a falsifying proposition will itself have its own falsifiers and we can never be sure the proposition is true, but unless the proposition is absolutely logically incompatible with the theory it's not a falsifier.

Comment: Rees earlier describes what he takes to be "Popperian analysis":"*The growth of scientific knowledge had little or nothing to do with the accumulation of data, and everything to do with daring, inspired, or even dotty conjecture, which was then to be exposed to the most ingenious, persistent, and tireless criticism that could be mounted against it. The point was to bury conjectures not to justify them.*" This, indeed, does not resemble data gathering and piecemeal Bayesian updating of phenomenological parameters in "Baconian'' sciences of "practical and applied-scientific orientation".

Comment: @Conifold: I see; so the point is that the kind of incremental building of models [of limited temporal accuracy] that seem to be done in meteorology is seemingly failing the spectacular conjecturing that happened elsewhere, e.g. in relativity (as Rees mentions Eddington's experiment on Einstein's theory). So building (e.g. regression) models by adding some variables "here and there" until they fit the data better seems to a Baconian process of sorts.

Comment: I remember lorenz system of equations quantitatively describe meteorology only for the short term (1 or 2 days forward), which is unlike Maxwell's system of equations definitely describing all EM phenomena. I believe their innate difference due to the complexity levels innately different for basic physics vs other sciences such as meteorology (which has way too many phase space variables like pressure, temperature, wind, humidity, etc...) Popperian analysis is much harder and complicated to apply to the latter case...

Comment: @DoubleKnot: it seems to depends on the scale of the grid. The coarser/global models seem to be feasible up two weeks or so; the "meso" models only for 2-3 days https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/model-data/model-datasets/numerical-weather-prediction. In general, the debate on the status of computer models (in such applied, large-scale problems) seems to be involved... https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/simulations-science/#ComSimStrSciThe

Comment: No scientific discovery has been the result of an application of "Bacon's rules" as well as "Popper's rule". The difference is that while Bacon aimed at describing "rules" whose application can produce real knowledge, this was not Popper's aim. Popper want to discriminate between "good" and "pseudo-" science (demarcation).

Comment: Having said that, Popper's definition can be (perhaps) applied to theories, but not to predictive models: think at current AI predictive models that work (and perform well) but the "designer" does not know the algorithm that the model uses. These sort of models are tools based on statistics that do not "incarnate" a theory.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: agreed with the AI (ANNs) kind of models. The issue with meteorology seems a bit different though as the kinds of models involved use less opaque predictive mechanisms, simply based on fluid mechanics etc. It's just that to get a good *practical* model for weather prediction it's not feasible to just use "first principles" and a lot of computation, but one needs a substantial amount of historical data to make the problem more tractable see (the somewhat idiosyncratically named) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_output_statistics used in meteorology.

Comment: Correct; in a nutshell, we cannot "refute" fluid mechanics equations simply because yesterday weather forecast were wrong. The amount of "science" involved into a predictive model is "too big" compared to the simplified Popper's model: e.g. Newton's Law of gravitations.